# NSTextField dragging values

Tags: macos, cocoa, custom-controls, nstextfield, nscontrol

I am trying to create a text field in the Mac OSX environment that allows a user to select a number and drag horizontally to adjust that number up and down.
I know this can be done because Apple have implemented it in the inspector panel of the Sprite Kit emitter section: see the image[image]

I have tried sub classing NSTextField to capture mouse drag events and doing the math, but they don't seem to get passed through. The mouse down event does though...

I have also tried placing a dummy view over the top and catching events as they come through. This works for mouse down, but again, the mouse dragged is never called. I know that the view can receive the mouse dragged event though, because if I place that view somewhere that a text field isn't under it, everything works fine.

What are my options here? I feel I have tried everything and the only option left is to create a new control from scratch. I don't mind that too much, but I also want the user to be able to add equations in the text field and drag individual values - that means the full functionality of NSTextField will need to be rebuilt just to add this dragging feature... Is there anything else???